# Can't access string in struct

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
const struct config{
    private:
        std::string file;
        config() : file(getConfig()) {}
    public:
        std::string failsafe = file.substr(file.find("failsafe") + 12);
        failsafe.resize(failsafe.find("\""));
        size_t ran, price, expiry;
    } *ini;
```

Line 7 - Error: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier.
I'm puzzled. Why can't I access failsafe?

Comment: You can't call functions like `substr` or `resize` inside a structure declaration. Use your constructor to do this.

Comment: You can't run code inside a struct like that. Everything except for declaring your fields  has to be inside a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. I put your code, plus added some dummy code (ie: getConfig) into MSVC2010 to test and fix it.

- In nearly all cases, [Constructors](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/overview-ctors.html) ( config() ) [have to be public](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29#C.2B.2B). After all, how
  else will it be accessed to initialize the object. I moved the constructor to the Public area.
- The code (find(), substr()) must be inside a function. Either main(), the constructor of the object, or some function/method. I moved your code into the constructor.
- I did not add anything to handle errors (such as not finding the substrings you are looking for), but you may consider adding some code to handle those situations.

---

```
const struct config{
private:
    std::string file;
public:
    config() : file(getConfig()) {
        failsafe = file.substr(file.find("failsafe") + 12);
        failsafe.resize(failsafe.find("\""));
    }
    std::string failsafe;
    size_t ran, price, expiry;
} *ini;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason [Constructors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29) are there is for initializing members, which you try to attempt when you are declaring them.

```
const struct config{
    private:
        std::string file;
        config() : file(getConfig()) {
            failsafe = file.substr(file.find("failsafe") + 12);
            failsafe.resize(failsafe.find("\""));
        }
    public:
        std::string failsafe; 
        size_t ran, price, expiry;
    } *ini;
```

Comment: The `file.substr()` line may not do what you intend if `failsafe` is not found in the string, it'd be better to store the result of `find` and check it was found before doing the `substr`.